# How do I retrieve INCREMENT for Sequences in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task

`(select INCREMENT from TEST_DB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES`

Why this is not working but it working in other properties retrieval

Answer (score 2):

Increment is [a reserved word](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/reserved-keywords.html), therefore you need to write your query as this:

```
select "INCREMENT" from TEST_DB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES
```